# How to get QoQ, MoM values from previous years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with quarterly values for various items and I need to create a column showing quarter values from previous year of each item (Ex: 2021_Q1 value of item A to be compared with 2020_Q1 and so on for other items) similarly for MoM.

Below is my reproducible dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
                  'quarter':['FY20_Q1','FY20_Q2','FY20_Q3','FY20_Q4','FY21_Q1','FY21_Q2',
                         'FY20_Q1','FY20_Q2','FY20_Q3','FY20_Q4','FY21_Q1','FY21_Q2',
                         'FY20_Q1','FY20_Q2','FY20_Q3','FY20_Q4','FY21_Q1','FY21_Q2'],
                  'value':[100,150,120,135,128,160,230,210,240,220,250,230,125,230,162,111,134,135]})
```

I sorted values and used `groupby` and `shift` but I am not getting desired result.

```
df['value_prev'] = df.sort_values(by=['item','quarter']).groupby(['item'])['value'].shift()
```

This gives me below result which obviously is comparing values from preceding quarter and not year.

```
  item    quarter    value    value_prev
0  A      FY20_Q1     100       NaN
1  A      FY20_Q2     150       100
2  A      FY20_Q3     120       150
3  A      FY20_Q4     135       120
4  A      FY21_Q1     128       135
5  A      FY21_Q2     160       128
...
```

My expected result  is as below. Is there any method which can be used to get this.

```
  item    quarter    value    value_prev
0  A       FY20_Q1    100       NaN
1  A       FY20_Q2    150       NaN
2  A       FY20_Q3    120       NaN
3  A       FY20_Q4    135       NaN
4  A       FY21_Q1    128       100
5  A       FY21_Q2    160       150
```

Comment: Are  you guaranteed to have an entry for each quarter, i.e. would `shift(4)` work?

Comment: @BigBen That might work only for few items but there are lot more items where values are not guaranteed in each quarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert the "Quarter" to PeriodIndex
df["current"] = df["quarter"].str.replace(r"FY(\d+)_Q(\d+)", r"20\1-Q\2", regex=True)
df["current"] = pd.PeriodIndex(df["current"], freq="Q")
df["next"] = df["current"] + 4

out = df.merge(
    df,
    how="left",
    left_on=["item", "current"],
    right_on=["item", "next"],
)
print(
    out[["item", "quarter_x", "value_x", "value_y"]].rename(
        columns={"quarter_x": "quarter", "value_x": "value", "value_y": "value_prev"}
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
   item  quarter  value  value_prev
0     A  FY20_Q1    100         NaN
1     A  FY20_Q2    150         NaN
2     A  FY20_Q3    120         NaN
3     A  FY20_Q4    135         NaN
4     A  FY21_Q1    128       100.0
5     A  FY21_Q2    160       150.0
6     B  FY20_Q1    230         NaN
7     B  FY20_Q2    210         NaN
8     B  FY20_Q3    240         NaN
9     B  FY20_Q4    220         NaN
10    B  FY21_Q1    250       230.0
11    B  FY21_Q2    230       210.0
12    C  FY20_Q1    125         NaN
13    C  FY20_Q2    230         NaN
14    C  FY20_Q3    162         NaN
15    C  FY20_Q4    111         NaN
16    C  FY21_Q1    134       125.0
17    C  FY21_Q2    135       230.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a challenge because your "quarter" column actually contains 2 pieces of information.. the quarter and the year.

Let's break up that column, build a pivot table, and you'll be good to do whatever analysis you need. This will also be guaranteed not to work in case of some missing records.

Step 1: Break up that complicated column into 2 (the code here works for your dummy data - maybe a more complicated function that handles exceptions will be needed for all of your productive data. But fore sure you have to break up these 2 dimensions!)

```
df['year'] = df['quarter'].str[0:4]
df['quarter'] = df['quarter'].str[-2:]
```

Step 2: Let's rearrange the years and quarters into rows and columns (these are apparently 2 different dimensions and you want to run different analysis, e.g., compare quarter to quarter would be a row-operation, vs. year to year would be a column operation) - do this for only 1 product, or all products, as you please

```
sorted_df = df.pivot_table(index='year', columns=['quarter', 'item'])
```

Step 3: Pick whatever analysis you want to do now.. say for all products look at the 'value' for 'Q1' across years:

```
sorted_df['value']['Q1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which extracts the year and subtracts 1, creates a new dataframe (`d`) with the subtracted year column, merges with the initial dataframe (`df`) to get the values corresponding to the adjusted years, and, finally, adds the `value` column of `d` as `value_prev` column of `df`:

```
cols = ['quarter', 'item']
y = df['quarter'].str.extract('FY(\d+)_.*').astype(int).sub(1)[0]
q, item = df['quarter'].str.extract('.*_(.*)')[0], df['item']

d = (pd.DataFrame(
     [[f'FY{x[0]}_{x[1]}', x[2]] for x in zip(y, q, item)], columns=cols)
     .merge(df, on=cols, how='left'))

df['value_prev'] = d['value']
```

Output:

```
   item  quarter  value  value_prev
0     A  FY20_Q1    100         NaN
1     A  FY20_Q2    150         NaN
2     A  FY20_Q3    120         NaN
3     A  FY20_Q4    135         NaN
4     A  FY21_Q1    128       100.0
5     A  FY21_Q2    160       150.0
6     B  FY20_Q1    230         NaN
7     B  FY20_Q2    210         NaN
8     B  FY20_Q3    240         NaN
9     B  FY20_Q4    220         NaN
10    B  FY21_Q1    250       230.0
11    B  FY21_Q2    230       210.0
12    C  FY20_Q1    125         NaN
13    C  FY20_Q2    230         NaN
14    C  FY20_Q3    162         NaN
15    C  FY20_Q4    111         NaN
16    C  FY21_Q1    134       125.0
17    C  FY21_Q2    135       230.0
```